# Missing App Bar Template in Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows Phone 8

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone, windows-phone-8, application-bar

according to [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394040%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), there should be an Application Bar template in every generated Xaml File for Windows Phone Projects:

> Locate the sample Application Bar element, which is added to your page by default. It looks like the following.

I've created a new empty Windows Phone 8 project in Visual Studio 2012 and I'm missing the App Bar template which was visible when I developed for Windows Phone 7. Is this only deactivated or do I need to copy and paste the code snippet for the creation of an App Bar when I'm developing Windows Phone 8 projects?

Comment: I came across the app bar as a control when I opened Blend.  You can add it in the same way as any other control.  I found this odd too though as I was under the impression it would be included by default too.

Comment: Hm I'm missing the Application Bar as a control element in Blend. But I can see the ApplicationBar as element of my PhoneApplicationPage. But I'm not seeing the menu items or icons for adding. It is somehow disturbing that I need to add this all by myself everytime I'll want to use it :/

Comment: I agree. The fact that WP7 had it added automatically and WP8 doesn't is odd. Perhaps they've made it "simpler" by making it harder to do, true to form.

Comment: I guess I've found a possible solution for this problem:

Starting with Windows Phone 8, the code for the ApplicationBar was moved from the XAML code to the C# code behind. My guess it has something to do with the localization of the ApplicationBar.

But there's no trace of the ApplicationBar anymore in the XAML code :(

Comment: That's odd.  I have to say I don't see the point behind this particular change.  Well done on finding a solution though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found no other solution than to copy and paste the XAML code into my WP8 projects like this (code taken from [this page](http://programming4.us/mobile/2330.aspx)):

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
<shell:ApplicationBar Opacity="1" IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
            <shell:ApplicationBar.Buttons>
               <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar.add.rest.png"
Text="add">
               </shell:ApplicationBarIconButton>          


<shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar.save.rest.png"
Text="save">
               </shell:ApplicationBarIconButton>
               <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar.delete.rest.png"
Text="delete">
               </shell:ApplicationBarIconButton>
            </shell:ApplicationBar.Buttons>
            <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="Menu Item 1" IsEnabled="True">
                </shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="Menu Item 2" IsEnabled="True">
                </shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem>
            </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
        </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

Microsoft encourages users to [use the localizable ApplicationBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff637520%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_LocalizinganApplicationBar) instead it seems.